# How to use CImg functions with pixel data?

Tags: c++, cimg

I am using Visual Studio and looking to find a useful image processing library that will take care of basic image processing functions such as rotation so that I don't have to keep coding them manually. I came across CImg and it supports this, as well as many other useful functions, along with interpolation.

However, all the examples I've seen show CImg being used by loading and using full images. I want to work with pixel data. So my loops are the typical:

```
for (x=0;x<width; x++)
for (y=0;y<height; y++)
```

I want to perform bilinear or bicubic rotation in this instance and I see CImg supports this. It provides a rotate() and get_rotate function, among others.

I can't find any examples online that show how to use this with pixel data. Ideally, I could simply pass it the pixel color, x, y, and interpolation method, and have it return the result.

Could anyone provide any helpful suggestions? If CImg is not the right library for this type of this, could anyone recommend a simple, light-weight, easy-to-use one?

Thank you!

Comment: what matters more than the loop-headers you use to iterate over your pixel data is the layout in memory. Is it RBG interleaved, is it color planes, does it have a row-stride or is it tightly-packed? If you have that information you might be able to wrap a pointer to the image-data with a "shared" CImg and do the operations in-place without extra copying.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You've only seen CImg used with full images - do you somehow want to process part of an image then? You want to use loops - fine, you can use loops with CImg. You want to use pixel data - all raster images have pixel data, so what's stopping you handling pixel data. You can create a CImg containing pixel data. I don't see what part you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy pixel data to `CImg` class using iterators, and copy it back when you are done.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> pixels_src, pixels_dst;
size_t width, height, n_colors;

// Copy from pixel data
cimg_library::CImg<uint8_t> image(width, height, 1, n_colors);
std::copy(pixels_src.begin(), pixels_src.end(), image.begin());

// Do image processing

// Copy to pixel data
pixels_dst.resize(width * height * n_colors);
std::copy(image.begin(), image.end(), pixels_dst.begin());
```